# Conditionally modify multiple variables

Tags: python

Not quite sure what the correct title should be.

I have a function with 2 inputs `def color_matching(color_old, color_new)`.  This function should check the strings in both arguments and assign either a new string if there is a hit.

```
def color_matching(color_old, color_new):
    if ('<color: none' in color_old):
            color_old = "NoHighlightColor"
    elif ('<color: none' in color_new):
            color_new = "NoHighlightColor"
```

And so forth.  The problem is that each of the arguments can be matched to 1 of 14 different categories ("NoHighlightColor" being one of them).  I'm sure there is a better way to do this than repeating the if statement 28 times for each mapping but I'm drawing a blank.

Comment: I think you need to provide some examples input/output of your function, I think it's not really clear what do you ask

Comment: Are `color_old` and `color_new` in a specific format?
perhaps you can construct a dictionary where these all possible formats that are a hit are the keys and the values are the new assigned value for each key. Then you can use the `get()` method of a dictionary and define that the default value (in case of no match) will be the original value itself

Comment: `color_old` and `color_new` are strings that always begin with `<color: ` before a color.  It is that color that I want to assign/match to a new string.  A dictionary might work... Interesting idea.

Comment: @Shawn is the elif there on purpose ? I mean if the `color_old` value gets a 'hit' does the `color_new` check should be skipped?

Comment: @Oleg You are correct, if color_old gets hit then color_new can be skipped.  But if color_new hit on `none`, then we could skip color_old.  This is the logic puzzle i was wrestling with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can at first parse your input arguments, if for example it's something like that:
`old_color='<color: none attr:ham>'`
you can parse it to get only the value of the relevant attribute you need:
`_old_color=old_color.split(':')[1].split()[0]`
That way `_old_color='none'`

Then you can use a dictionary where `{'none':'NoHighlightColor'}`, lets call it `colors_dict`
`old_color=colors_dict.get(_old_color, old_color)`

That way if `_old_color` exists as a key in the dictionary `old_color` will get the value of that key, otherwise, `old_color` will remain unchanged

So your final code should look similar to this:

```
def color_matching(color_old, color_new):
    """ Assuming you've predefined colros_dict """
    # Parsing to get both colors
    _old_color=old_color.split(':')[1].split()[0]
    _new_color=new_color.split(':')[1].split()[0]
    # Checking if the first one is a hit
    _result_color = colors_dict.get(_old_color, None)
    # If it was a hit (not None) then assign it to the first argument
    if _result_color:
            color_old = _result_color
    else:
        color_new = colors_dict.get(_color_new, color_new)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace conditionals with a data structure:

```
def match(color):
    matches = {'<color: none': 'NoHighlightColor', ... }
    for substring, ret in matches.iteritems():
        if substring in color:
            return ret
```

But you seems to have a problem that requires a proper parser for the format you are trying to recognize.

You might build one from simple string operations like `"<color:none jaja:a>".split(':')`

You could maybe hack one with a massive regex.

Or use a powerful parser generated by a library like  [this one](https://lark-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)